# How to fix "Details page" error in datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm setting up a new page with details of element, and want to support nvarchar values in my page. Where do i need to change code ?

My controller

```
 public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("TimeSheet", "AllTimeSheet");
                }
             MainTimeSheetView objMT = new MainTimeSheetView();
                objMT.ListofVacationsDayoffs = _ITimeSheet.GetVacationsbyTimeSheetMasterID(Convert.ToInt32(id));


                objMT.TimeSheetMasterID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                return View(objMT);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

My class

```
public class GetVacations
    {
        public string Vacations { get; set; }
    }
```

My list with query to procedure

```
 public List<GetVacations> GetVacationsbyTimeSheetMasterID(int TimeSheetMasterID)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimesheetDBEntities"].ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    var param = new DynamicParameters();
                    param.Add("@TimeSheetMasterID", TimeSheetMasterID);
                    var result = con.Query<GetVacations>("Usp_GetVacationsbyTimeSheetMasterID", param, null, true, 0, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
                    if (result.Count > 0)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new List<GetVacations>();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

And html where i'm trying to display nvarchar values from database, it's working only if i convert my values to int.

```
@model WebApp.Models.Model

      foreach (var item in Model.ListofVacationsDayoffs)
   {
      <td><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vacations)</b></td>

   }
```

And the public class of MianTimeSheetView

```
  public class MainTimeSheetView
    {

        public List<GetVacations> ListofVacationsDayoffs { get; set; }

    }
```

My procedure is

```
SELECT     

      CASE WHEN Hours = 1 THEN  0
      WHEN Hours = 2 THEN 0
      WHEN Hours = 3 THEN 0
      WHEN Hours = 4 THEN 0
      WHEN Hours = 8 THEN 8
      ELSE 0
      END
        AS Vacations
  FROM [TimeSheetDetails]    t  
  where TimeSheetMasterID =@TimeSheetMasterID
```

Comment: What does the stored proc return?

Comment: procedure is returning one column with nvarchar values and i converted those values for now, to integer, because page stops working with nvarchar values

Comment: there nothing, just error page appears. I'm sure that is cause of datatype of column, if i'll change back from nvarchar to int, it will work and page will appear.

Comment: Please could you provide `MainTimeSheetView` class

Comment: added to the question (bottom)

Comment: One issue I see is that `ListofVacationsDayoffs ` is never defined. You assign a value but it is never defined. I would suggest either having a constructor in the model class that sets it to a new list or setting it to a new list before trying to assign a value. What do you mean as well when you say 'it's working only if i convert my values to int'?

Comment: I've added procedure to theme, i mean if i add to "case" statement after "then" = N'Something' it won't work, with integer values it's working

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but it should be the other way around since your model is string and not int. Can you also post the exact error your are receiving?

Comment: because of catch i guess, page just not displaying to me specific error and redirecting me to error page, but it's working immediately, if i change it to int value.

Comment: Remove the `catch` to get the error, in development it will provide full error.

Comment: removed catch, still not showing the error.

Comment: Have you removed all the try and catch codes from all the codes? Can you make sure you are in development environment? (By default you should be if using visual studio to run the project and settings are not changed manually) If both true sorry I could not help, hopefully others will.